# Create Macro template to use on Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, criteria, vba

I would like to know if it is possible (AND HOW) to create a Excel template with a specific Macro to use this Macro automatically at Spreadsheets we are exporting from our measurement hardware.

We export the measurements from our hardware into an Excel Spreadsheet. Now we have to write for every Spreadsheet the same Macro to filter specific criteria we only need.

So we would like to have one Excel Template with this Macro saved in it, to import the Excel Spreadsheet from our hardware so it automatically filters the criteria every time, so we can use it immediately.

How can we arrange this?

Comment: Do you want to import this template directly in your hardware's program, or what?

Comment: @PeterL. makes a good point, is the template stored on your PC or on your measurement device? If it's stored on your PC you could make an add-in and just add it as you normally would an add-in; meaning the macros will be available to you every time you open Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If a assume your measurement hardware always produce the same output file name...

- 1 - You could have a template with the macro that imports and filter your data file.
  In this scenario, the file with the macro would not server as a template per see

Sub LoadDataSheet()

```
Dim sWbkPath As String
sWbkPath = "PATH_TO_FILE\" & "FILE_NAME"

Dim wbkData As Workbook
Set wbkData = Workbooks.Open(sWbkPath)

DataFilteringMacro wbkData 'or sheet
```

End Sub

- 2 - You could have an addin that shows a ribbon only when the data file is open

In the "ThisWorkbook" module...

Dim WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

```
Set App = Application
```

End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

```
'...
'if using a ribbon, you could put the code in the "GetVisible" callback
'and invalidate the ribbon in the App_WorkbookActivate()
'bVisible is the value set in the ribbon callback

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

If wbk.Name = "FILE_NAME" Then

    'bVisible = True 'the data file was loaded

Else

    'bVisible = False 'another file was loaded

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: @PeterL this template must be stored on our PC. We export the data from our hardware by an excel spreadsheet. Then we would like to import this data into a excel spreadsheet with implemented Macro, so during importing the data it filters automatically the crteria we ounly would like to see..

Comment: Both methods discussed above can be stored on individual PCs or on a shared drive. You can send the template or addin by email to other workers... Another user would just need a copy of the template/addin to import the data.